# Remove <HR> from first loop entry

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I have this simple loop:

```
foreach ($links as $link)
{   
    echo '<div>';
        echo '<table>';

        echo '<tr><td class="fullwidth"><a class="preview_img" href="' . $link . '"><img src="' . $link . '" title="Click to enlarge" width="300" class="thumb" /></a></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td><span class="default">Direct:</span>&nbsp;';
        echo '<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="link-area" onmouseover="this.select();" value="' . $link . '" />'; 
        echo '</td></tr>';

        echo '<hr /><br>';
        echo '</table>';
        echo '<br>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

And the `<HR>` shows up in pretty weird way. The horizontal line shows up in the beginning of the loop too, something that should not be happening, because I need ALL except the first loop entry to include the `<HR>`. I tried to be as clear as possible, hopefully I was. If there is any way to help me, please do it :).

Thanks

Comment: You should not inject hr tag inside a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do

```
     $flag = false;
     foreach ($links as $link)
    {   
        if ($flag)
             echo '<div class='line'>';
        else
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<table>';
           echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td class="fullwidth"><a class="preview_img" href="' . $link . '"><img src="' . $link . '" title="Click to enlarge" width="300" class="thumb" /></a></td>'
  echo '</tr>';
           echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td><span class="default">Direct:</span>&nbsp;';
             echo '<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="link-area" onmouseover="this.select();" value="' . $link . '" />'; 
            echo '</td></tr>';
            echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
      $flag=true;
    }
    ?>
```

With the class='line' you can manage border and distance between div
without use hr and br

Comment: You should not inject hr tag inside a table

Comment: I wrote that answer quickly and I not saw that the  table was non closed yet... copy and paste... my fault

Comment: I hope to understand the request

Answer (score 2):

The `<HR>` tag is in wrong place. If you have any content out of `<td>` tag in the table, it will be displayed in top of the table.

If you want to have `<HR>` effect please have bottom border for div or place the `<HR>` tag after the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
foreach ($links as $link)
{   
    echo '<div>';
        echo '<table>';

        echo '<tr><td class="fullwidth"><a class="preview_img" href="' . $link . '"><img src="' . $link . '" title="Click to enlarge" width="300" class="thumb" /></a></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td><span class="default">Direct:</span> ';
        echo '<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="link-area" onmouseover="this.select();" value="' . $link . '" />'; 
        echo '</td></tr>';


        echo '</table>';
echo '<hr /><br>';
        echo '<br>';
    echo '</div>';
}

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a counter, because then you can use the counter for other things as well testing to see what iteration we are one. For example, every 5 iterations, add a blank row for a spacer or whatever.

```
$counter = 0;          // Set the counter outside the foreach
foreach ($links as $link)
{   
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><td class="fullwidth"><a class="preview_img" href="' . $link . '"><img src="' . $link . '" title="Click to enlarge" width="300" class="thumb" /></a></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><span class="default">Direct:</span>&nbsp;';
    echo '<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="link-area" onmouseover="this.select();" value="' . $link . '" />'; 
    echo '</td></tr>';

    if($counter == 0) // You can use this counter to test for other things
    {
        echo '<hr /><br>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '</div>';

    $counter++;       // Increment the counter by one.
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$showHR = false;
foreach ($links as $link)
{   
    echo '<div>';
        echo '<table>';

        echo '<tr><td class="fullwidth"><a class="preview_img" href="' . $link . '"><img src="' . $link . '" title="Click to enlarge" width="300" class="thumb" /></a></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td><span class="default">Direct:</span>&nbsp;';
        echo '<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="link-area" onmouseover="this.select();" value="' . $link . '" />'; 
        echo '</td></tr>';
        if(!$showHR){

         $showHR = true;
        } else {
         echo '<hr /><br>';
         }

        echo '</table>';
        echo '<br>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

This will hide hr line once only.

Comment: You should not inject hr tag inside a table